# Creating a regex from regular language

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I need to create a regex from this language:

$L = \{w\sigma \mid w \in (\Sigma − \sigma)^*; \Sigma = \{a, b, c, d, e\} ; \sigma \in \Sigma\}$

but I don't understand the logic of this language.

If $\sigma \in \Sigma$ then $w$ is just an empty group, isn't it?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have it the wrong way around: $\sigma \in \Sigma$

Comment: you could try to build a regex for each possible choice of $\sigma$, then combine them to get a regex for $L$.

Comment: So σ could be a,b,c,d,e, {a,b}, {c,d} and etc... right?

Comment: I understand this to mean "the language where each word is built with all but one letter, concatenated with that letter".

Comment: So I actually looked at it the wrong way.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Actually $\sigma$ is one of the letters $a, b, c, d, e$, which gives you five possibilities. For instance, if $\sigma = a$, then $\Sigma - \sigma = \{b,c,d,e\}$ and thus $w \in \{b,c,d,r\}^*$. Does it help you to find the regular expression?

Comment: It really helps.
Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome.